# Whenever I upload images on firebase then shows the error like "no auth token for request"

Tags: file-upload, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-storage

These are the errors terminal shows

1. no auth token for request.
2. Please sign in before trying to get a token.
3. StorageException has occurred.
4. User does not have permission to access this object.
5. Code: -13021 HttpResult: 403.
6. The server has terminated the upload session.
7. {  "error": {    "code": 403,    "message": "Permission denied. Could not perform this operation"  }}

Comment: It would be useful to include your exact method for "uploading images TO firebase." How are you uploading them? Where are you attempting to upload them to exactly? A database in firebase? a storage space? etc. What commands and/or script code are you using to perform the uploads? Include all of your sample code and/or commands here with code snippets.

Comment: since the the StorageException  throw out. Please confirm that is except ['Firebase.Storage.StorageException'](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/unity/class/firebase/storage/storage-exception)?  Can you explain more details about how you request, it means your runtime, your app running environment, and parts of the  cedes of the request.